# Moodle customiziation using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, moodle

HI i want develop new learning site using moodle. i want to apply my own bootstrap framework for front end but the functionality should be moodle. Please give me any suggestions or tutorial links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me Google that for you :)

https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Bootstrap

Comment: thanks for the reference link Russell but my problem is not cleared, for example in wordpress first we can build a template as per client requirement again we build theme development which we can use the functionalitys of wordpress, the same case here also am looking i want my own style of layout with same functionality of moodle. thanks in advance

Comment: i got another alternate am trying it, for modifying and adding the page but now the problem is how to set those pages to navigation bar ..? from the below code we can create new pages <?php

require_once('config.php');

$PAGE->set_context(get_system_context());
$PAGE->set_pagelayout('standard');
$PAGE->set_title("About page");
$PAGE->set_heading("About");
$PAGE->set_url($CFG->wwwroot . '/about.php');


echo $OUTPUT->header();

// Actual content goes here
echo "Hello World";

echo $OUTPUT->footer();

?>